# Unhexlify data to pdf with python

Tags: python, pdf

In my programm, I get data as binary ascii format from the server. 
Now I want to unhexlify and save the data in a file output.pdf -
this does not work:

```
data = unhexlify(data)

pdf_hdr = b'%PDF-1.5'

if len(data) >= len(pdf_hdr) and data[:len(pdf_hdr)] == pdf_hdr:

    file = open("output.pdf", "w")
```

The line breaks are not formatted correctly...beginning of the pdf looks like this:

```
b'%PDF-1.5\n%\xd0\xd4\xc5\xd8\n24 0 obj <<\n/Length 2374      \n/Filter /FlateDecode\n>>\nstream
```

How can I get the correct formatted PDF? (I know that the data I retrieve is 
valid)

Comment: Just spitballin here, but had you tried a for loop, after your if statement that is checking for the pdf header, to write line by line? In doing so you could manually set the line breaks by inputting your own '\n', after the specified lines. Obviously this is not optimal, just food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
with open('yourfile','w') as f:
f.write(data.decode("ascii", "ignore"))
```

However, I still get errors from decoding.. Maybe you have an idea here?!
Btw, it´s network security @TUM right?